# Only happening on AppStore - Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, crash, storyboard, app-store, nib

So I'm getting a crash when I try and open a view controller from a storyboard. The weird thing about it, is that it works perfectly fine on every build from debug builds to release builds which are being distributed through hockey app. The only time it crashes is when the app is downloaded from the appStore.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'ContactUsViewControllerIdentifier' and directory 'Main.storyboardc'
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this or even how to replicate it on a build that I can debug through Xcode. Also how do I go about testing the fix because I can't replicate the crash unless I use the appStore version which I can't run through the debugger.

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide code where you try to load your controller from nib?

Answer (score 0):

You need to beta testing your app using [Distributing Your App Using Ad Hoc Provisioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) per instructions from this Apple document.

Comment: I've done beta testing through HockeyApp and Testflight and it doesn't crash. It only crashes once it gets updated to the appStore.